# Composer autoload missing classes in some sub-folders

Tags: php, docker-compose, composer-php, slim, autoload

I am trying to improve my file structure, as my `validators` folder is quickly filling up. To improve this, I want to add new sub-folders inside this folder in order to keep everything organised and manageable. However, in doing so, **my application no longer correctly autoloads all the required files. Specifically, it misses out any files inside a sub-folder of `/validators`** (see structure below)

```
v1
|-- validators
  |-- sessionValidators
```

The autoload part of my `composer.json` file looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "./",
        "v1",
        ...
        "v1/validators",
        "v1/validators/sessionValidators"
    ]
}
```

I am unsure if having `v1/validators` and `v1/validators/sessionValidators` might be the issue.

I have tried removing `v1/validators/sessionValidators` from `composer.json`, but of course that did not work.

**To be clear, everything was being loaded just fine before I tried moving things into the new `sessionValidators` folder.**

---

The Slim code with is unable to find the `SessionValidator` class looks like this:

```
$app->put('/session', 'SessionResource::updateSession')->add('SessionValidator');
```

I have tried changing it to this, to no avail:

```
$app->put('/session', 'SessionResource::updateSession')->add('sessionValidators/SessionValidator');
```

I *can* get the code to execute by adding this to the top of the Slim routing file:

```
require_once 'validators/sessionValidators/SessionValidator.php';
```

However, this is not an elegant solution as I would have to do this for every single file in a folder inside `/validators`, and there's a lot of those.

I've seen repeatedly that regenerating the autoload file should solve this issue, however I don't think that's the case here. When I re-run my docker-compose the autoload file should be re-generated automatically; see the Docker files at the end of this post.

---

Everything aside from `v1/validators/sessionValidators` seems to be loaded correctly. When I try to make a request or run a test which requires a class inside the `sessionValidators` folder, I get this **error**:

`/var/www/html/vendor/php-di/invoker/src/Exception/NotCallableException.php (33) 'SessionValidator' is neither a callable nor a valid container entry #0 /var/www/html/vendor/php-di/invoker/src/CallableResolver.php(80)`

If it happens to be relevant, I am running all this inside a Docker container, though I don't believe that will be the issue.

---

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  salus-db:
    image: postgres:11.2
    volumes:
      - ./tests:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - 7000:5432

  salus-api:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ${CONFIG_PATH}:/var/www/html/conf
      - ${HOST_LOG_PATH}:/var/www/html/salus_api_log
    env_file:
      - api.env
    ports:
      - 9191:80
    depends_on:
      - salus-db
    links:
      - salus-db:salus-db
```

Dockerfile

```
# Build Dockerfile from official PHP 7.3 image
FROM php:7.3-apache

# Create new user 'deploy'
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash deploy

# Copy contents of current directory into /var/www/html/ inside the container
COPY . /var/www/html/

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
            php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

USER deploy

# Install Composer dependencies without autoloader
RUN composer install --no-autoloader

# Copy new contents
COPY . ./

# Generate autoload.php
RUN composer dump-autoload

USER root

ADD apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

# Expose port 80 inside the container
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload` after moving class files to different directory?

Comment: I re-run my docker-compose, which includes this command `RUN composer dump-autoload`. I will add my Docker files to the question.

Comment: @rob006 I've added those files :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, the reason for this was I wasn't using [namespaces](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) correctly and consistently.